# What does "resistor as a reference" means?

Tags: arduino, resistors, piezo

I have a book with some projects examples that use Arduino, one of the projects use piezo to detect vibrations. The book says the following:

> When plugged into 5V, the sensor (piezo) can detect vibrations that can be read by the Arduino's analog inputs. You'll need to plug in high value resistor (like 1-megaohm) as reference to ground for this to work well.

The book also says in other page:

> Lower resistor values will make the piezo less sensitive to vibrations.

What does this mean? What does "resistor as a reference" means? And why would the piezo be less sensitive with less value resistors?

I don't have any experience in electronics, I started learning one week ago, and resistors are one of the most confusing things for me.

Project's circuit scheme:
[image]

Comment: piezo parts are high impedance and dont generate much current but with small currents going thru high R values like 1 Meg, you get V=IR  ( sorry megaohm)

Comment: If you add the schematic diagram into your question we may be able to help you better.

Comment: @Transistor Done

Comment: Where are you getting these weird white-on-brown schematics, anyway? They look like they're printed on wood or something.

Comment: @DaveTweed from the book I mentioned in the question, the book has some projects and in each project there is scheme for the circuit used in the project, I captured it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In very simple terms, the piezo transducer can give out highish voltages when subject to vibrations. The piezo transducer has extremely high internal resistance - you can try to measure it on the highest range of your multimeter ohms range - so the current it can give out is very low. As a result we call this a "high-impedance source". (Impedance can be thought of as resistance to current flow.)

Your microcontroller analog input has an input range of 0 to 5 V DC and to get best use of this our signal into it should be in that range of voltages. A 0 to 0.5 V signal, for example, would only use 1/10 of the range of the ADC (analog to digital converter) and for your microcontroller I think that would give you 102 possible values out of 1024.

To maximise the voltage from your weak transducer you need to feed the small current into a high value resistor. With the 1 MΩ value in your circuit we can see from Ohm's Law that you will reach 5 V when the current from the transducer is \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {5}{1M} = 5 \ \mu \text A \$.

The design of the circuit isn't great. The transducer may give out negative voltages or voltages higher than 5 V and they are relying on the microcontroller's internal protection diodes to prevent damage to the IC. A commercial design would be likely to include external protection.

---

> You'll need to plug in high value resistor (like 1-megaohm) as reference to ground for this to work well.

I think we've covered this. The resistor converts the current from the transducer to a voltage for the microcontroller.

> Lower resistor values will make the piezo less sensitive to vibrations.

We've covered this. A lower value resistor will result in a lower voltage for a given current from the transducer.

> What does "resistor as a reference" means?

It is a poor choice of words. It is really a "load" for the piezo to convert current to voltage.

> And why would the piezo be less sensitive with less value resistors?

Explained above.

> Resistors are one of the most confusing things for me.

Resistors can be used to limit current in a circuit, decrease the voltage or to convert current into voltage. Keep up your studies and you will start to see where they are used and why as you read more circuits.